# Identifying premature expiration

Tags: sql

The dataset I have is a bit tricky. It’s a rolling calendar for a period of 24 months, and the data is published only once a month.
The relevant data points are as follows:
•   CaseNumber (int)
•   Start_date (date)
•   Reporting_month (date)
•   Months_old (int)

The above ‘CaseNumber’ has the ‘potential’ to appear in a ‘Reporting_month’ as many as 24 times (0-23). However each ‘CaseNumber’ will only appear one time in each ‘Reporting_month’.
So if you list any # of months in chronological order (Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, etc.) a single ‘CaseNumber’ is will show up in each one of those ‘Reporting_months’ as long as the ‘CaseNumber’ is < 23 ‘Months_old’.

However, once a ‘CaseNumber’ = 24 ‘Months_old’ it will no longer report in this data set. So the oldest any particular ‘CaseNumber’ will ever be in this reporting cycle is 23 ‘Months_old’. Any older, than it will not appear on this report.

What I’m interested doing is tracking these ‘CaseNumbers’ to see if any are dropping off of this report prematurely. So in doing so I need to be able to compare the current ‘Reporting_month’ to the previous ‘Reporting_month’ to determine if any of the ‘CaseNumbers’ prematurely dropped off.

```
Example:
Case #  Previous    Current     
        Months_old  Months_old  Status  
1234    22          23          Correct age
5678    23          NULL        Dropped due to age
9101    18          NULL        Premature drop
```

only means i've been able to achieve this is via a VLOOKUP formula in excel done manually. I'd like to get away from having to complete this manually.

```
SELECT
a.[CaseNumber]
,CONVERT(DATE,MAX(a.[Month]),111) 'Month'
,CASE WHEN m2.[CaseNumber] IS NOT NULL 
    AND m1.[CaseNumber] IS NULL 
    THEN 'Yes' 
    ELSE 'No' 
 END as 'New Default'

FROM
[dbo].['v2-2yrTotalDefault$'] a
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        [CaseNumber] 
    FROM
        [dbo].['v2-2yrTotalDefault$'] 
    WHERE
        LEFT(CONVERT(varchar,[Month],112),6) = '201902') m1
        ON m1.CaseNumber = a.CaseNumber --most current month

LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        [CaseNumber] 
    FROM
        [dbo].['v2-2yrTotalDefault$']
    WHERE
        LEFT(CONVERT(varchar,[Month],112),6) = '201903') m2
        ON m2.CaseNumber = a.CaseNumber --previous month

WHERE
a.[Month] > '12/01/2018'

GROUP BY
a.[CaseNumber]

ORDER BY
a.[CaseNumber]
```

/*the continually errors out due to the following error:
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
Column 'm2.CaseNumber' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
Column 'm1.CaseNumber' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.*/

additionally with the above i don't want to have to hard code the months in the SELECT statement. I'd like to be able to control what month i'm looking to view in the WHERE clause.

in the end i'd like the results to return to columns, one reflecting previous months 'age' in months, and the second showing current month 'age'. if a CaseNumber dropped off prematurely, i'd like the current month to say 'premature_expiration'.

Comment: The error you are getting is clear - you've included fields in your `SELECT` clause which do not appear in your `GROUP BY` clause and are not contained within an aggregate function (like `MIN`, `MAX`, etc.).
To help solve your underlying problem though, can you provide some sample input data (i.e. example rows from `[dbo].['v2-2yrTotalDefault$']`) and your expected output from that input?

Comment: They only relevant data points are the ones listed, and the desired output is what i've already listed as well in my initial query. I understand the error, but like i had also mentioned i'm trying to be able to control what month i'm viewing via the 'WHERE' clause. I dont want to have to adjust in the SELECT statement.

Comment: You don't show any example data from your source table `[dbo].['v2-2yrTotalDefault$']` - where can we see example value pairs values for `CaseNumber` and `Month` from that table, as referenced in your query? You have only provided an example of desired output, without any example of the input data. You need to help us to help you.